# Navigator Permissions check on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, geolocation, navigator

I have created a geolocation javascript code that detects the user location based on the navigator variable.

The location check is done based on the permissions the user currently has.

I check the `navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'})` and based on the `granted|prompt|denied` results, I make a `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` query or a fallback API request.

My problem here is that on IOS devices, Safari browser, the `navigator.permissions` is undefined.

If I make a direct `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` query then the "allow location on device" prompt is always opening which is something I do not want.

Only if the user has already allowed the use of location and the status is `granted` I will make a position query.

In case the permission is on `denied` state, there is an "Allow Location" button that on click, the navigator prompt will happen.

It works flawlessly on desktop/Android devices, but on IOS we cannot use `navigator.permissions` variable and we do not want our users to be prompted to "allow location" on the website entry.

Some of the code for reference:

```
if (navigator.permissions) {

   permissionsIsActive = true;
}
......
if (permissionsIsActive){

   makePermissionsQuery();
}else{

   makePositionQuery();
}
......
var makePositionQuery = function () {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (devicePos) {


                isAccurate = true;
                position = {
                    lat: parseFloat(devicePos.coords.latitude),
                    lng: parseFloat(devicePos.coords.longitude)
                }

                //inject granted status as this is an if dependent variable
                //so we make sure its in place for the prompt statement
                permissionsStatus = 'granted';


                isFinished = true;
            },function () {

                handleGeoError();
            });
        }
......
var makePermissionsQuery = function() {

            navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(function (result) {

              
                permissionsStatus = result.state;

                switch (result.state) {

                    case "granted":

                        makePositionQuery();
                        break;
                    case "prompt":

                        handleGeoError();
                        break;
                    case "denied":

                        handleGeoError();
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
```

So my question is, how can we detect the permission status on an IOS device, safari?

I am not sure if I messed or missed anything but any advice would be helpfull!